# Failed to start OpenVPN service for client

Tags: openvpn

```
root@ip-10-0-0-4:/var/log# systemctl status openvpn-server@client
● openvpn-server@client.service - OpenVPN service for client
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openvpn-server@.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2024-02-27 17:18:01 IST; 836ms ago
     Docs: man:openvpn(8)
           https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage
           https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO
  Process: 4937 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --status /run/openvpn-server/status-client.log --status-version 2 --suppress-timestamps --config client.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 4937 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 27 17:18:01 ip-10-0-0-4 systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenVPN service for client.
```

Comment: An error message is not a question.

Comment: Please [edit] with the rest of the error message

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.